# How can I use variable in $_POST[....]

Tags: php, variable-variables

That's my code:

```
for($zm=1; $zm<=$ilosc; $zm++){
$aaa.$zm = $_POST['bbb.$zm'];
}
```

I want to use variable

```
$zm in $_POST --> ( $_POST['bbb.$zm'] );
```

What is the proper form?

Comment: Try double-quotes `"` to interpret the variable

Comment: yes, but look at the codes, he wants to use variable variables dear Hashem ;)

Comment: 'variable variables' is what was necessary in my case

Comment: @AlirezaFallah Yes, I just read the the question carelessly.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$var = "aaa".$zm;
$$var =  $_POST["bbb".$zm];
```

OR :

```
$var = "aaa".$zm;
$$var = $_POST["bbb{$zm}"];
```

its called [**variable variables**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) .